# 2 Kings 9-10 genealogy question

Tags: 2-kings

2 Kings 9: 8 tell us that "The whole house of Ahab will perish." In chapter 10 we are told that Jehu did all that the Lord "had in mind to do." If the whole house of Ahab was killed, then how is Joash, son of Ahaziah, still alive if Ahaziah is related to Ahab by the marriage of his father Jehoram to Athaliah (8:18)? Would he not be included as a member of the "house of Ahab," which would mean he should be dead by this point? I'm reading through Kings for the first time, so I am unaware of what happens to Joash after chapter 11.

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. A man fathers his own house; he does not become part of the house of his father-in-law. He is part of his father's house, but certainly not of his father-in-law's. Also, for women, marriage means moving from the authority of her father('s house) to that of her husband('s house), which is why, until this day, she usually changes her family name from that of her father to that of her husband. As such, neither Jehu nor his parents were ever part of the house of Ahab.

Comment: @lucian - I was going to write an answer along those lines but do not wish to seal your thunder.  Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Dottard: Why not ? Am I not a Romanian ? Did we not steal our language from the Italians, and our religion from the Jews ? Is our [national car](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_Dacia) not <ahem>borrowed</ahem> from the [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_12) ? Do our politicians not [dilapidate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_in_Romania) public funds ? As such, shouldn't others, according to the Law of Moses, do unto us as we have done unto them ? Or are you perhaps afraid of Thor's vengeance, for daring to steal said thunder ? But doesn't Fortune favor the brave ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some brief facts:

- Omri founded a new dynasty for the northern kingdom of Israel after killing Tibni
- His son Ahab was the second king of this "Omride" dynasty and ruled for 22 years
- The third king was Ahaziah who ruled for 2 years
- The fourth and last king was Joram who ruled for 12 years
- Jehu assassinated Joram and established a new dynasty.  Jehu ruled for 27 years.

As @Lucian has correctly pointed out (comment above):

> A man fathers his own house; he does not become part of the house of
> his father-in-law. He is part of his father's house, but certainly not
> of his father-in-law's.

There is another similar situation with the wife:

> for women, marriage means moving from the authority of her father's
> house to that of her husband's house.

Thus, it becomes quite clear that neither Jehu, the king of the northern kingdom of Israel, and Jehu's parents, were never part of the house of Ahab - Jehu founded a new dynasty in the northern kingdom

Comment: He who up-votes another, up-votes oneself.